# how get rid from blk_update_request error, and secure my drive from data loss

Tags: linux, smartctl

> ATA Error Count: 4060 (Note: The number of entries may be limited to the newest ones)

```
Complete error log:

SMART Extended Comprehensive Error Log Version: 1 (2 sectors)
Device Error Count: 4060 (device log contains only the most recent 8 errors)
    CR     = Command Register
    FEATR  = Features Register
    COUNT  = Count (was: Sector Count) Register
    LBA_48 = Upper bytes of LBA High/Mid/Low Registers ]  ATA-8
    LH     = LBA High (was: Cylinder High) Register    ]   LBA
    LM     = LBA Mid (was: Cylinder Low) Register      ] Register
    LL     = LBA Low (was: Sector Number) Register     ]
    DV     = Device (was: Device/Head) Register
    DC     = Device Control Register
    ER     = Error register
    ST     = Status register
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 4060 [3] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 19605 hours (816 days + 21 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 41 00 08 00 00 73 f8 80 08 40 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x73f88008 = 1945665544

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  60 00 00 00 08 00 00 73 f8 80 08 40 08     00:00:04.859  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 00 08 00 00 73 f8 80 08 40 08     00:00:04.863  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08     00:00:04.863  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 00 03 00 46 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08     00:00:04.863  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08     00:00:04.863  IDENTIFY DEVICE

Error 4059 [2] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 19605 hours (816 days + 21 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 41 00 08 00 00 73 f8 80 08 40 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x73f88008 = 1945665544

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  60 00 00 00 08 00 00 73 f8 80 08 40 08     00:00:04.859  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 00 08 00 00 73 f8 80 08 40 08     00:00:04.862  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 00 08 00 00 74 70 67 f0 40 08     00:00:04.862  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 00 08 00 00 74 70 67 80 40 08     00:00:04.861  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 00 08 00 00 1d 20 08 00 40 08     00:00:04.861  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 4058 [1] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 19605 hours (816 days + 21 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 41 00 08 00 00 73 f8 80 08 40 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x73f88008 = 1945665544

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  60 00 90 00 08 00 00 73 f8 77 f8 40 08     00:00:04.521  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 00 08 00 00 73 f8 80 08 40 00     00:00:04.482  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 08 00 40 00     00:00:04.519  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 0a f8 08 40 00     00:00:04.519  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 00 08 00 00 1c c0 08 00 40 00     00:00:04.519  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 4057 [0] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 19605 hours (816 days + 21 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 41 00 08 00 00 73 f8 80 08 40 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x73f88008 = 1945665544

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  60 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 08 00 40 08     00:00:04.489  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 00 08 00 00 73 f8 80 08 40 00     00:00:04.482  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 00 08 00 00 73 f8 7b 18 40 00     00:00:04.488  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 00 08 00 00 67 da 18 08 40 00     00:00:04.487  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 00 08 00 00 1c c0 08 00 40 00     00:00:04.487  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 4056 [7] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 19605 hours (816 days + 21 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 08 00 00 73 f8 80 08 e0 00  Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x73f88008 = 1945665544

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 73 f8 80 08 e0 08     00:00:04.027  READ DMA EXT
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08     00:00:04.027  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 00 03 00 46 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08     00:00:04.027  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08     00:00:04.027  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 73 f8 80 08 e0 08     00:00:04.025  READ DMA EXT

Error 4055 [6] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 19605 hours (816 days + 21 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 08 00 00 73 f8 80 08 e0 00  Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x73f88008 = 1945665544

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 73 f8 80 08 e0 08     00:00:04.025  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 73 f8 80 00 e0 08     00:00:04.025  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 74 70 67 f0 e0 08     00:00:04.025  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 74 70 67 80 e0 08     00:00:04.025  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 1d 20 08 00 e0 08     00:00:04.025  READ DMA EXT

Error 4054 [5] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 19605 hours (816 days + 21 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 08 00 00 73 f8 80 08 e0 00  Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x73f88008 = 1945665544

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 73 f8 80 08 e0 08     00:00:03.998  READ DMA EXT
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08     00:00:03.998  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 00 03 00 46 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08     00:00:03.998  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08     00:00:03.997  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 73 f8 80 08 e0 08     00:00:03.996  READ DMA EXT

Error 4053 [4] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 19605 hours (816 days + 21 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 08 00 00 73 f8 80 08 e0 00  Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x73f88008 = 1945665544

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 73 f8 80 08 e0 08     00:00:03.996  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 73 f8 80 00 e0 08     00:00:03.996  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 74 70 67 f0 e0 08     00:00:03.996  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 74 70 67 80 e0 08     00:00:03.996  READ DMA EXT
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08     00:00:03.996  IDENTIFY DEVICE
```

Initially, this error was first appeared by not finding the `swap` partition on boot located at `/dev/sda6`. Values present on */etc/fstab* was okay at that time.

But, */etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume* is set to `none`, so changed it to *UUID* of current swap & **update-initramfs -c -k all**, goes well. I thought restarting would solve the problem.

And, here it is... the output after *restart*.

I think  `40 -- 41 00 08 00 00 73 f8 80 08 40 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x73f88008 = 1945665544` <-- this refers to *uncorrectable errors(UNC)* & others may be read error(s). So, there may be a  chance of data loss.

Is there any solution? Is `btrfs scrub/rescue` helpful for this situation?

```
## output of lsblk -f

NAME FSTYPE FSVER LABEL      UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
sda
├─sda1
│    ntfs         System Reserved
│                            725C5C385C5BF577
├─sda2
│    ntfs                    368A6AD28A6A8DE5
├─sda3
│    ntfs                    4ECA9C7DCA9C62CF
├─sda4
│
├─sda5
│    btrfs                   b7714eed-50e7-4565-a6ac-75a4090e1a78     86G    10% /
└─sda6
swap   1                4f979523-7ce0-44c1-8056-1502e4ac73c7                [SWAP]
sr0

$ uname -a
Linux deb 5.7.0-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.7.10-1 (2020-07-26) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0):

Your drive is failing. Replace it immediately.

The error log indicates that READ operations fail. A problem related to software is unlikely.